# add number spaced apart in single cell in r

Tags: r, sum

I would like to add these numbers together in the following code in the col3.
I have tried using gsub, to add a + and calculate in r
I have tried using separate to do a sum across.

```
train <- data.table(col1=c(rep('a0001',4),rep('b0002',4)), col2=c(seq(1,4,1),seq(1,4,1)), col3=c("12 43 543 1232 43 543", "","","","15 24 85 64 85 25 46","","658 1568 12 584 15684",""))
```

I would like the results to be a sum of the number in col3 by row like in col4

```
result<-data.frame(col1=c("a0001","b0002"), col3=c("12 43 543 1232 43 543", "","","","15 24 85 64 85 25 46","","658 1568 12 584 15684",""),col4=c("2416",'18850'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouped by 'col1', we can split by the space, `unlist`, convert to `numeric`, get the `sum` and assign (`:=`) to create new column

```
train[, col4 := sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(col3, ' '))), na.rm = TRUE), col1]
```

---

Or another option is `scan`

```
train[, col4 := sum(scan(text = col3, what = numeric(), quiet = TRUE)), col1]
```